# Windows API MoveWindow returns true even if function did not succeed

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am trying to move process to 2nd screen using MoveWindow function:

```
while (!process.HasExited)
{
     IntPtr id = process.MainWindowHandle;
     if (id != IntPtr.Zero)
     {                   
          var result = MoveWindow(id,
                                Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.X),
                                Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.Y),
                                Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.Width),
                                Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.Height),
                                true);

     Thread.Sleep(500);

     if (result == true)
     {
            break;
     }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

So the issue I have is that sometimes this code works, sometimes it doesn't.

The reason why is because `MoveWindow` returns `true` and I exit this `while` loop using `break;` but the `MoveWindow` did not move it to 2nd screen correctly.

So if I remove `break;` it will work all the time but I will have `while` loop running all the time and that is not what I want.

Do you know how could I solve this issue?

Comment: Check the position of the window after an allegedly successful move with `GetWindowRect` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

Comment: That seems like the best solution. Thanks! @riQQ

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `SetWindowPos()` instead of `MoveWindow()`?

Comment: You should test `result` before you call `Thread.Sleep`. Is it possible you are calling this before the main window has been fully created and shown? You may need to test the window to see if it is on screen first. And possibly sleep before you attempt the move.

Comment: @vidara Can you call [`Process.Refresh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) additionally just before `process.MainWindowHandle` to see if you can still reproduce this issue?

Comment: Well I though ```result``` returns value ```true``` when it moves successfully to 2nd screen, but seems like it doesn't. @NetMage I tried ```process.refresh``` and it did not fix the issue. @MSFT

Comment: Is it the same program that sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails?

Comment: Are you sure the window has completed being drawn before you call `MoveWindow`?

Comment: @vidara Can you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample code? Because I can't reproduce this issue with my Win32 C++ demo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you tried *should* have worked but since it's not, try changing the condition that you are exiting on or try using a [do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loop like I have below.

```
IntPtr id = process.MainWindowHandle;
if (id != IntPtr.Zero)
{                   
    var result = false;
    do
    {
        result = MoveWindow(id,
            Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.X),
            Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.Y),
            Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.Width),
            Convert.ToInt32(secondScreen.WorkingArea.Height),
            true);

        Thread.Sleep(500); 
    } while (return != true && !process.HasExited)
} // This one was missing.
```

Comment: It is not working neither. For some reason MoveWindow returns true but it did not move the window to second screen successfully

Comment: I would also suggest moving `Thread.Sleep` to above the `MoveWindow` call :)